# How to validate drag and drop of an object in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In one of the test cases I need to check whether a particular object is dragged or not. I  should decide whether or not to pass the test case based on this.

Can anyone provide a way to check whether a particular object is dragged and dropped?

regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking that the object is dragged or not, would it be easier to check that the results are what you expect from it being dragged? For example the object is visible in table 2 instead of table 1?